# Finding four states each of six pairs of which have common boundary using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, topology, boundaries

A Mathematics SE question on [common boundary points of connected sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467746/common-boundary-points-of-connected-sets) inspires this one.

Construing the word "state" broadly (so that, for example, each province or territory of Canada is a "state") is there any place on earth where, among four states, each a contiguous region, every one of the six pairs among them share a common boundary that is not just a point?

(As a matter of geometry, this can happen with four regions but not with five or more.)

A map of the United States shows Colorado, New Mexico, Arizona, and Utah meeting at an isolated point, and in Canada the provinces of Manitoba and Saskatchewan and the Northwest Territories and the territory of Nunavut similarly share an isolated point. I don't know any others of that sort, but I suspect some exist.

(If the four states are A, B, C, D, then the six pairs are AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD.)

The following diagram shows a simplified topology.

[image]

The shared boundaries AB, AC, AD, BC, BD and CD should all be lines.

Comment: While GIS could be used to answer this question, I don't see how it's GIS-centric enough for GIS SE.

Comment: Besides, GIS software, can it be answered without tediously searching all maps covering the earth or else relying on sources that have contributions from someone who did that?

Comment: It would help if OP wants to clarify which GIS tools they want to use. I suspect it might be possible with any spatial database with de-9im support.

Comment: Could you draw a diagram of how four states can share more than a point, eg a line segment? I can't see how this is possible as a planar partition.

Comment: For CO, NM, OK, TX, you can get 5 of the 6.

Comment: @Spacedman : I can easily draw it and scan it in. Uploading images to stackexchange is something with which I lack experience. Also, look at the crude road-map drawing between capital cities in my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @Spacedman : I started drawing a simple example, but then Steven Kay posted a map that shows a real example.

Comment: @Spacedman : Or you can use this description: The three states of B, C, and D surround the state of A. As you circumnavigate the state of A in a clockwise direction just outside of its boundaries, you drive along the boundary between A and B (on the B side of the boundary) until you enter the state of C; then you drive along the boundary between A and C (on the C side of the boundary) until you enter D; then you drive along the boundary between A and D (on the D side of the boundary) until you cross the next boundary, thereby returning to B, having fully circumnavigated A.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, I took "common boundary" to mean the pairs all shared a common boundary - ie the border line between A and B was the same border line as between B and C and so on!

Comment: @Spacedman : Every PAIR shares a common boundary. "Pair" means just two.

Comment: @mkennedy : Having five of the six is actually typical. Another case is MN, WI, IA, IL. Another is MN, NE, SD, IA. Another is NY, CT, MA, VT.

Comment: Paraguay and Switzerland both seem to fit the new diagram.

Comment: @mkennedy : Paraguay does seem to match, since it is surrounded by Brazil, Bolivia, and Argentina. Switzerland is surrounded by four countries: Germany, France, Italy, and Austria so you have a set of five, with no boundary between Austria and France, nor between Germany and Italy.

Comment: @mkennedy : and also Lichtenstein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an attempt with postgis. i've used data imported from natural earth data, admin level 1, 1:10m scale.

This will take a long time as it's a 4-way cartesian join with st_relate().

The magic number "FF2F11212" should match when two polygons' intersections are a line, but not when they join at a point. This uses something called [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM). I use a [cheatsheet](https://www.flickr.com/photos/stevefaeembra/34500665382) i put together a while back to work out the value.

There are possibly mistakes in here, and potenial optimisations.

From my understanding, the question being

- are there any sets of 4 polygons which intersect
- their combinatorial intersections are ALL lines

I found 109 cases from Natural Earth data. Here's one example (I think...)

[image]

When this query returns, if there are no rows then the answer is false, otherwise it should list all groups matching the requirement.

```
select
    s_a.gid,
    s_b.gid,
    s_c.gid,
    s_d.gid,
    st_asewkt(s_a.geom),
    st_asewkt(s_b.geom),
    st_asewkt(s_c.geom),
    st_asewkt(s_d.geom)
from
    (select gid, geom from states) as s_a,
    (select gid, geom from states) as s_b,
    (select gid, geom from states) as s_c,
    (select gid, geom from states) as s_d
where
    -- this is a way 4 cartesian join so we need to avoid unneccessary checks!
    s_a.gid < s_b.gid and
    s_b.gid < s_c.gid and
    s_c.gid < s_d.gid and
    s_a.gid != s_b.gid and
    s_a.gid != s_c.gid and
    s_a.gid != s_d.gid and
    s_b.gid != s_c.gid and
    s_b.gid != s_d.gid and
    s_c.gid != s_d.gid and
    -- check combinations intersect
    st_intersects(s_a.geom, s_b.geom) and
    st_intersects(s_a.geom, s_c.geom) and
    st_intersects(s_a.geom, s_d.geom) and
    st_intersects(s_b.geom, s_c.geom) and
    st_intersects(s_b.geom, s_d.geom) and
    st_intersects(s_c.geom, s_d.geom) and 
    -- check each of 6 intersections is a line
    st_relate(s_a.geom, s_b.geom) = 'FF2F11212' and
    st_relate(s_a.geom, s_c.geom) = 'FF2F11212' and
    st_relate(s_a.geom, s_d.geom) = 'FF2F11212' and
    st_relate(s_b.geom, s_c.geom) = 'FF2F11212' and
    st_relate(s_b.geom, s_d.geom) = 'FF2F11212' and
    st_relate(s_c.geom, s_d.geom) = 'FF2F11212'
group by
    s_a.gid,
    s_b.gid,
    s_c.gid,
    s_d.gid,
    s_a.geom,
    s_b.geom,
    s_c.geom,
    s_d.geom
order by
    s_a.gid asc,
    s_b.gid asc,
    s_c.gid asc,
    s_d.gid asc
    ;
```